# The strange (for me) case of Mod of Iota.

Tags: complex-numbers

This might be a silly question to some, but I need some help in this topic. 
Iota, denoted as *'i'* is equal to the principal root of -1. 
Therefore,

$\iota^2 = -1$

When studying Modulus, I was wondering..

$|\iota| = ?$

A Google search revealed that the value is **+1**. This is because of the equation:

$z = x + y\iota$;
$Therefore, |z| = \sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$

Substituting the value of $0 + 1\iota$, we get our value. But how was this equation derived, and why would it hold true, since, if $\iota$ is +1, $\iota$ must be equal to either +1 or -1, making it a Real Number. My doubt is not analytical but intuitive. As it is an abstract concept, I
am having trouble understanding it.

Sorry for the lack of understanding of any fundamental concepts that render this question redundant. But, sadly, I do not know them, and would appreciate any help you gave me for understanding these.

Comment: $|x|=1\implies x=\pm1$ is only true for $x\in\mathbb{R}$; when we generalize modulus to $\mathbb{C}$ this is no longer true as you pointed out.

Comment: how the hell are we cheating our way out of a paradox? there are uncountably many $z\in\mathbb{C}$ that satisfy $|z|=1$ -- consider $t\mapsto\exp(it)$. This is true. You are wrongly assuming that $|i|=1\implies i=\pm1$ holds for complex numbers when it clearly does not.

Comment: Well, that was a little too direct, apparently. My point is, I'm either not understanding this solution, or I'm not satisfied by it. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer, so that we can discuss and vote on it there?

Comment: we can define $|z|$ by identifying $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $(\Re\{z\},\Im\{z\})\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and by analogy with $|\cdot|:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{\ge0}$ defining it as the Euclidean distance from $(\Re\{z\},\Im\{z\})$ to $(0,0)$

Comment: Hold on there. I understand what x ∈ ℝ and, therefore z ∈ ℝ would mean, but z ∈ ℝ<sup>2</sup>? I am new to this field of Mathematics. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An axiomatic definition of $\mathbb C$ follows from its construction from $\mathbb R^2 = \{(x,y) : x \in \mathbb R, y \in \mathbb R\}$.  An abbreviated treatment follows, and a rigorous treatment can be found in Walter Rudin's classic text *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

We **define** a complex number $z \in \mathbb C$ as an ordered pair $z = (a,b)$ of reals, that obey the following rules for addition and multiplication:  for $z = (a,b)$ and $w = (c,d)$, we have $$\begin{align*} z \color{red}+ w &= (a,b) \color{red}+ (c,d) = (a \color{blue}+c, \; b\color{blue}+d), \\ z \color{red}\cdot w &= (a,b) \color{red}\cdot (c,d) = (a\color{blue}\cdot c \color{blue}- b\color{blue}\cdot d, \; a\color{blue}\cdot d \color{blue}+ b\color{blue}\cdot c), \end{align*}$$ where we have color coded the binary operations to emphasizes that the red symbols are operations in $\mathbb C$, and blue symbols are operations in $\mathbb R$.  From this definition, it is easy to check that the field axioms are satisfied--that is to say, $(\mathbb C, \color{red}+, \color{red}\cdot )$ is a field, with additive identity $(0,0)$ and multiplicative identity $(1,0)$.  We also can see that $\mathbb C$ contains a copy of $\mathbb R$ as a subfield:  explicitly, $(a,0) = a$.  Next, we can also see that $$(0,1)^2 = (0,1) \cdot (0,1) = (-1, 0) = -1,$$ so that the element $(0,1)$ has the property that its square equals $-1$.  We **define** $$i = (0,1).$$  From this, we can now observe that for real numbers $a, b$, we can write $$(a,b) = (a,0) + (0,b) = a(1,0) + b(0,1) = a + bi.$$  Throughout this, we have not needed to appeal to square roots.  Now, the **magnitude** of a complex number is again defined by its Euclidean norm in $\mathbb R^2$:  the function $|\cdot| : \mathbb C \to \mathbb R^{\ge 0}$ is defined as $$|(a,b)| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}.$$  Then the fact that there are infinitely many such ordered pairs whose magnitude is $1$ is a direct consequence of elementary geometry in the real Euclidean plane.

Comment: It takes a while to digest this. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can define modulus as $|x|$= $\sqrt{x^2}$.

So, since i=$\sqrt{(-1)}$

|i|=$\sqrt{(-1)^2}$

=$\sqrt{1}$

=1

Edit:

Actually can someone confirm if this makes sense?